# How can i render a specific Django admin page from a view?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-urls

I know that can reverse to admin pages from a template by doing this:

> {% url 'admin:index' %}

or

> {% url 'admin:app_model_add' %}

But how can i render an admin page using the render function in my view?

When i do

> render(request, template_name='admin/index.html')

I get a blank looking admin page with the message "You do not have permission to view or edit anything"

Furthermore, I am not sure what the syntax would be to render a specific admin template, i.e. the equivalent of using this reverse in a template:

> admin:app_model_add

is not something like this in a view:

> render(request, template_name='admin/app_model_add.html')

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What do you mean, "render an admin page"? The admin renders the admin pages; you can link or redirect to it.

Comment: Ok thanks that helped me work it out. I want to redirect rather than render so in fact i need to do redirect(to=reverse('admin:app_model_add'))

Comment: Post your admin view please.

Answer (score 1):

In fact i shouldn't to try to render an admin page, i should redirect to it.

so in my view I should be using:

> redirect(to=reverse('admin:index'))

or

> redirect(to=reverse('admin:app_model_add'))

Comment: Please add some advice with -1, a downvote on it's own is not really useful to anyone